# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, admin-bar

I am using a Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top and I have added this css to drop it below the admin bar:

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
  .logged-in .navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-top: 46px;
  }
}

@media screen and ( min-width: 782px ) {
  .logged-in .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 32px;
  }
}
```

This is working fine for everything above 600px, but once it drops below that the admin bar is no longer fixed (which is fine) and there is a gap above the navbar where it used to be. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Lookee here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26609

Comment: I'll make this into an answer, so we can close off this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `admin-bar.min.css` at 600px, `#wpadminbar` is changed from `position:fixed` to `position:absolute`. [The reason](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26609) the adminbar scrolls at mobile sizes is because a fixed-height, fixed-position element causes major problems when you tap/pinch-to-zoom in mobile browsers. So, you can fix this by overriding WP's native css on `#wpadminbar`, but then the behaviour is deliberate.